# Why isoelectronic species give similar spectral lines?

Tags: physical-chemistry, atomic-structure

In my perspective those species should give similar spectra those which have same energy of different energy levels as the transition would yeild same energy photon
But still the answer to this question is always the isoelectronic species
Not the ions of the element

Comment: ?? The spectral lines of $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Ne}$ do not have the same energies.

Comment: But Mg+2 and Al+3 gives series of similar spectral lines (this was the question of my exam i.e.NEET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: comment

> Isoelectronic species will not have an identical matching spectrum" ok, but will they be similar but why the spectrum of Mg+2 not similar to Mg and why to Al+3 or Na+

This should really be another question be here goes anyway...

The answer is complicated.

**Non-isoelectronic species**

$\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Mg}$ are not isoelectronic. Hopefully it will suffice to say that in quantum mechanics there are [selections rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_coupling) about what electron transitions between orbitals are "allowed" and which are "forbidden." The forbidden transitions do occur but with a very much reduced probability compared to the allowed transitions.

The gist is that because of the selection rules the pattern of lines for non-isoelectronic species will be different.

**Isoelectronic species**

Because of the pattern of allowed transitions isoelectronic species will have a similar parrern of spectral lines but at slightly different energies due to the difference in atomic number. Thus since they are isoelectronic  $\ce{Na+}$, $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$, and $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ have a similar pattern of spectral lines but at different energies.

---

There is also another factor in all of this. [Slater's Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules) give a rudimentary method for calculating shielding between orbitals. However quantum mechanics shows that the actual shielding mechanism is more complicated because the spatial distribution of the orbitals depends not only on the electron orbitals which are filled, but also on the atomic number of the nucleus.

Answer (score 3):

You are completely forgetting the nuclear charge of isoelectronic series. Their valence shell configuration is the same but the electrons experience a different attraction in each. As you stated

> $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ give series of similar spectral lines
> (this was the question of my exam i.e.NEET)

Yes the spectrum *pattern* is similar but not identical. Atomic spectrum and that of ionized atoms is like a fingerprint, otherwise identifying the elements in the stars will become difficult and perhaps impossible. There is certainly some overlap in atomic spectrum but not identical as your question title suggests. A quick search of Google shows that this non-sensical question is quite popular in local exams. It is wrong. Isoelectronic species will not have an identical matching spectrum. Even the wavelengths are different.

Search this title in Google Scholar to see the wavelengths of isoelectronic series, where it available free of charge. None match with neutral sodium spectrum.

*Wavelengths and levels of the Na I isoelectronic sequence from K IX through Mn XV*
Journal of the Optical Society of America Vol. 66, Issue 9, pp. 899-904 (1976)

Comment: Yes, similar $\ne$ same...

Comment: " Isoelectronic species will not have an identical matching spectrum" ok, but will they be similar but why the spectrum of Mg+2 not sumilar to Mg and why to          Al+3 or Na+

Comment: This must have a deeper quantum mechanical explanation. I do not know. Keep in mind, after hydrogen multielectron atoms are very challenging to deal with theoretically.